# Jquery/Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to query/javascript and having a problem with the following code to calculate a gross value and tax amount based 
on the net amount the user enters. The user will enter a double amount and the gross and vat amounts are also defined as doubles. 
Can anyone help? I get an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number" when i try running the following code.

```
                $('#netPayment').change(calcLowerVatRateAndGrossAmount);
                /* $('#netPayment').change(function(){
                    calcLowerVatRateAndGrossAmount();
                }); */                  
    });     

    function calcVatRateAndGrossAmount(){                       
        var netPayment = parseFloat($('#netPayment').val());                        
        var vatAmount = 00.0;
        var VatRate = 20.0;
        var grossPayment = 0.00;
        var totalPaymentAmount = 0.00;
        if (netPayment !== '') {
            vatAmount = (netPayment * VatRate) / 100;
            grossPayment = (netPayment - vatAmount);                        
            $('#vatAmount').val(parseFloat(vatAmount.data).toFixed(2));
            $('#grossPayment').val(parseFloat(grossPayment.data).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $('#vatAmount').val(vatAmount.amountNull);
            $('#grossPayment').val(grossPayment.amountNull);
        }
    };
```

Comment: detail the problem so we know what to look for please

Comment: 1) What is the problem? 2) A little detail on the `.data` and `.amountNull` properties would be helpful.

Comment: since `vatAmount` is a number, what do you expect `vatAmount.data` to be? Similarly for `grossPayment` and for `.amountNull`?

Comment: The syntax error you quote lies outside the code you quote.

Comment: If the user enters 1000.00 and the vatrate is 20.00 i'd expect the vatAmount.data to be 200.00 and the grossAmount to be 8.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you calculate a number here

```
vatAmount = (netPayment * VatRate) / 100;
```

And in here, you treat `vatAmount` as an object that has a key `data`

```
$('#vatAmount').val(parseFloat(vatAmount.data).toFixed(2));
```

You should just be using the variable. A simple test

```
console.log("variable itself: ", vatAmount);
console.log("key data: ", vatAmount.data);
```

So you would need to just do

```
$('#vatAmount').val(vatAmount.toFixed(2));
$('#grossPayment').val(grossPayment.toFixed(2));
```

You do the same thing with `grossPayment` and you reference some other property `vatAmount.amountNull`

```
$('#vatAmount').val(vatAmount.amountNull);
$('#grossPayment').val(grossPayment.amountNull);
```

should be

```
$('#vatAmount').val("");  //or any error message
$('#grossPayment').val("");
```

Comment: `parseFloat(vatAmount)` is still wrong.

Comment: Please note syntax error / typo questions should be closed. Did you vote to?

Comment: @JanDvorak What would be wrong with parseFloat of a number? It will just return a number.

Comment: Even if it works, it will be wrong ;-) How will the result differ from the argument?

Comment: thanks its looking better! When I add a new amount it calculates the correct values but when I blank out the net amount the existing values remain.  How do I replace the gross and vat amounts with spaces when the user performs this action?

Comment: Well put a space into the input...